# can't update data into MySQL using PHP ...... Can you help me

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens .

```
elseif($do=='Update'){//Update Page
                echo "<h1 class='text-center'>Edit Member</h1>";
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
                    $id     = $_POST['User_id'];
                    $user   = $_POST['username'];
                    $email  = $_POST['email'];
                    $name   = $_POST['full'];

                    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET Username = '?', Email = '?', Fullname = '?' where User_id='?'");
                    $stmt->execute(array($id,$user,$email,$name));
                    echo $id . $user . $pass . $email . $name;
                    echo $stmt->rowCount() . 'Record Update';
                } else{
                    echo "Sorry You Can't Browse This Page Directly";
                }
            }

    include $tpl .'footer.php';

} else {

    header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Your values in the binding also appear to be out of order. `$id` should be last, or you should use named placeholders so you can be sure they are binding when expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove those single quote marks (`'`) from before and after question marks (`?`) and there you go!

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep the order in the prepared statement

```
$stmt->execute(array($user,$email,$name,$id));
```

but you shpould add error management to your code during development

also single quotes aren't necessary around placeholders

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET Username = ?', Email = ?, Fullname = ? where User_id= ?");
```

Comment: remove extra single quote from update query ;)